# Try / catch in a do-while loop to check user input (array) - wrong boolean initialization and position

Tags: java, exception, try-catch, do-while

I am a Java beginner and I am learning to manage Exceptions and 2D arrays.
I am doing an exercise to plot in a 2D array the result of the sales of different car models.

I have mixed the way to deal with Exception by using a try catch or by throwing a custom Exception. On a custom Exception I have an issue I am not able to solve.

In the Seller class:

- In line 16, IDE tells me that the variable "correct" initializer to
  false is redundant [image: redundant initialization]
- In line 26, IDE tells me that the while    condition is always false.
  [image: Wrong final condition for do while loop]

I wanted to declare the boolean correct inside the inner loop to check for each value if the input was correct (an integer) or not and then to change the value to true at the end of the try in case the parseInt was successful. By reading the comments from the IDE I understand that the boolean correct is never changed to true even if I select an integer but I do not understand why.

```
import java.util.Scanner;
public class Sellers {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws NumberArrayException {
        Scanner myObj = new Scanner(System.in);

        int nbrOfSellers = CheckInput.control("Enter the number of sellers = ");
        int nbrOfModels = CheckInput.control("Enter the number of models = ");
        int[][] sales = new int[nbrOfSellers][nbrOfModels];

        String[] nameOfSellers = Characters.construction("seller", nbrOfSellers);
        String[] nameOfModels = Characters.construction("model", nbrOfSellers);


        for(int i = 0; i < nbrOfSellers; i++) {
            for(int j = 0; j < nbrOfModels; j++) {
                boolean correct = false;
                System.out.print("Enter the sales for the seller " + nameOfSellers[i] + " for the model " + nameOfModels[i] + " = ");
                do {
                    try {
                        String input = myObj.nextLine();
                        sales[i][j] = Integer.parseInt(input);
                        correct = true;
                    } catch (NumberFormatException e) {
                        throw new NumberArrayException();
                    }
                }while (!correct) ;
            }
        }
        for(int i = 0; i < nbrOfSellers; i++) {
            for(int j = 0; j < nbrOfModels; j++) {
                System.out.print(sales[i][j] + " ");
            }
            System.out.println();
        }
    }
}

import java.util.Scanner;
public class Characters {
    public static String[] construction(String character, int maxSize) {
        Scanner myObj = new Scanner(System.in);
        String[] myArray = new String[maxSize];
        for(int i = 0; i < maxSize; i++) {
            System.out.print("Enter the name of the " + character + " ");
            myArray[i] = myObj.nextLine();
        }
        return myArray;
    }
}

import java.util.Scanner;
public class CheckInput {
    public static int control(String message) {
        boolean correct = false;
        int number = -1;
        Scanner myObj = new Scanner(System.in);
        do {
            try {
                System.out.print(message);
                String input = myObj.nextLine();
                number = Integer.parseInt(input);
                correct = true;
            } catch(NumberFormatException e) {
                System.out.println("Enter a number");
            }
        }while(!correct);

        return number;
    }
}

public class NumberArrayException extends RuntimeException {
    public NumberArrayException() {
        super();
    }
}
```

Comment: The ide thinks that ``correct`` is always true.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code is pretty good and well structured.  Actually, you should compare the source of `CheckInput.control` to see why it does not have the mentioned warnings: you initialize the local variable `correct` as it should be *and* no exception is thrown in case of invalid input, thus letting the user to correct it.  If you throw an exception from inside `do-while` loop as in the `main` method, then the `false` value of `correct` is never used.

You should resolve these warnings by reusing existing `CheckInput.control` when initializing the 2D `sales` array.  Also there's a typo when creating `nameOfModels` -- `nbrOfModels` should be passed as an argument.

```java
String[] nameOfSellers = Characters.construction("seller", nbrOfSellers);
String[] nameOfModels = Characters.construction("model", nbrOfModels);


for(int i = 0; i < nbrOfSellers; i++) {
    for(int j = 0; j < nbrOfModels; j++) {
        sales[i][j] = CheckInput.control("Enter the sales for the seller " + nameOfSellers[i] + " for the model " + nameOfModels[i] + " = ");
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much @Alex Rudenko, indeed there is a typo in my code for getting nameOfModels string array. And thank you very much for your correction. Actually my brother told me to test both methods (try...catch and throwing exception to be more familiar with both, that is why I used a different approch here but I understand it was not the best case. I will create another exception to test if the input is negative (a car number should not :) ) and there I will use the throwing approach. Again thank you

Answer (score 2):

There are two ways that this *do-while-loop* can exit: `correct` is *true* or an exception is thrown.

Technically, an exception can only be thrown in the two lines above the statement `correct = true`. Since you are throwing the `NumberArrayException` inside the loop, it will either exit because of it, or `correct` will be set *true*.

When we reach `while (!correct)`, then `correct` is always true since it got set. Otherwise we would have exited with an exception. Therefore, this loop never has a second iteration.

To fix it, you can just avoid throwing an exception when the provided input cannot be parsed. The loop will then let the user enter another integer.

```
do {
    try {
        String input = myObj.nextLine();
        sales[i][j] = Integer.parseInt(input);
        correct = true;
    } catch (NumberFormatException e) {
        // output error message for the user here
    }
} while (!correct);
```

Answer (score 1):

When you throw an exception it exits the function and throws the exception. So instead of throwing the exception in the catch block just print and error message. So that user can understand the error and enter input again.

```
 do {
     try {
          String input = myObj.nextLine();
          sales[i][j] = Integer.parseInt(input);
          correct = true;
          } catch (NumberFormatException e) {
                System.out.println("Wrong input format. Please enter a number");
          }
 }while (!correct) ;
```

Comment: Hello @Suvajit Patra, thank you for your comment. As I mentioned the goal was to learn managing exceptions. As there are 2 possibilities by using try ... catch or throwing the exception I wanted to make the exercise using both to be familiar with both of them. Your solution is similar to try ... catch I have used in the class CheckInput. I am quite confortable with this solution but I would like to understand my mistake to be able to use both solutions. Thank you anyway for your feedback.